# materialize dbt model in custom schema

Tags: model, macros, materialize, ref, dbt

I have model2.sql in my dbt project

---

select *
from {{ ref('model1') }}

---

after compilation I need to get

select *
from 'dwh'.'analytics'.'model1'

and materialized it into schema "analytics_test" as "analytics_test.model2"

---

how can I reference the model via "{{ ref('model1') }} " from one schema ( for ex. from "analytics" ). and materialize this model into another (for ex. "analytics_test")

Comment: Have tried setting your dev schema in your `profiles.yml`?